# Hardcode a form in Contact Form 7

Tags: plugins, theme-development, plugin-contact-form-7

I've been digging a little into Contact Form 7 source code without success, but I was wondering if, like in Advanced Custom Fields, it's possible to hardcode a complete form (fields, recipients and required rules) in a theme using the WordPress API.

I don't expect a good straightforward way, but at least a way that I could deploy my websites without having to depend on DB-specific inputs.

Also, I don't refer to [this solution](http://contactform7.com/faq/#Can_I_embed_a_contact_form_into_my_template_file), that uses a `do_shortcode` and still needs us to create the forms.

Has anyone done something similar with Contact Form 7?

Comment: What do you need exactly that WPCF7 can't provide? I've created some custom forms, but all in the context of WPCF7 and I haven't felt the need to actually code the form itself.

Comment: I would like to use WPCF7 functionalities, verifications and e-mails without having to create forms in the admin interface, as these forms are meant to be deployed with the rest of the website. So, in this perspective, better to hardcode them like we can do in ACF.

Comment: @toscho, didn't quite understand why the question is off-topic. I see it as WordPress specific as it is a theme development idea around the WordPress API, and Sormano gave a good clue of what's possible.

Comment: Well, just saw this: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3844/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-question-about-how-to-use-a-specific-plug-in-here :)

Comment: @vmassuchetto The solution is specific to that plugin, not to WordPress.

Comment: Yup, just saw that.... thanks for putting this in hold @toscho.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked for this some time ago.

Best thing you can do is change the default contact form.

Filter you can use: `wpcf7_default_template`

Info can be found in contact-form-7/includes/functions.php file line 63

The filtered variable is:

```
$template =
    '<p>' . __( 'Your Name', 'contact-form-7' ) . ' ' . __( '(required)', 'contact-form-7' ) . '<br />' . "\n"
    . '    [text* your-name] </p>' . "\n\n"
    . '<p>' . __( 'Your Email', 'contact-form-7' ) . ' ' . __( '(required)', 'contact-form-7' ) . '<br />' . "\n"
    . '    [email* your-email] </p>' . "\n\n"
    . '<p>' . __( 'Subject', 'contact-form-7' ) . '<br />' . "\n"
    . '    [text your-subject] </p>' . "\n\n"
    . '<p>' . __( 'Your Message', 'contact-form-7' ) . '<br />' . "\n"
    . '    [textarea your-message] </p>' . "\n\n"
    . '<p>[submit "' . __( 'Send', 'contact-form-7' ) . '"]</p>';
```

Hope this helps.